# Shared instance of a configuration object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

**The Problem**

I'm developing a simple Ruby CLI that needs to store its configuration information in a flat file. I have a `Configurator` class that takes care of all the data management, saving to the filesystem, etc.

Although it's perfectly legitimate to instantiate `Configurator` objects at will, I'd also like to provide a shared instance (such that it becomes available everywhere in the CLI). There seem to be *a lot* of perspectives on the right way to do this in Ruby and I'm swimming in them. :(

**My First Stab**

*configurator.rb*

```
class Configurator
  attr_reader :config_path

  def initialize(path)
    @config_path = File.expand_path(path)
  end

  # ... more implementation
end
```

*configuration.rb*

```
module Configuration
  @@configuration = nil

  def configuration
    if @@configuration
      @@configuration
    else
      fail 'Attempted to access `configuration` before ' \
      'executing `load_configuration`'
    end

    def load_configuration(path)
      @@configuration = Configurator.new(path)
    end
end
```

Knowing this, my `Configuration` module might be used this way:

```
include Configuration

# Initialize our shared Configurator.
Configuration.load_configuration('~/.app_config')

# Use it.
p configuration
# => #<Configurator:0x0000010126f8e8 @config_path="/Users/abach/.app_config">
```

I've verified that this works, but there are several bad smells:

1. Running `Configuration.load_configuration` feels weird; don't know how else to say it. That could very well be *my* problem, though. :)
2. Using class variables in a Module doesn't seem right, either.

**Thoughts?**

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you write you configuration management for the purpose of learning how to do such a thing, or did you just want to solve a problem (*Ruby CLI that needs to store its configuration information in a flat file*)?

In the latter case, please have a look into [the Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Configuration_Management), especially [Configuration](https://github.com/ahoward/configuration).

Comment: While interesting to look at, the configuration library doesn't suite my needs (for example, it stores its data in Ruby, whereas mine needs to be be accessible to non-Ruby environments).